# Effective way to avoid changing texture layout in Vulkan every frame

Tags: textures, vulkan

I have some texture data that updates very rarely but I cannot control when it updates (data is provided from an external library that renders GUI).

Currently, I change their layout twice in every frame:

1. from `VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_DST_OPTIMAL` to `VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_SHADER_READ_ONLY_OPTIMAL` with pipeline stages `VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_TRANSFER_BIT` to `VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_FRAGMENT_SHADER_BIT`,
2. and then from `VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_SHADER_READ_ONLY_OPTIMAL` to `VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_DST_OPTIMAL` with stages `src=VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_FRAGMENT_SHADER_BIT` to `dst=VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_BOTTOM_OF_PIPE_BIT`.

I think, such transformations that happen every time may be wasteful because I almost always don't have any updates for my textures, so I am thinking about implementing this procedure:

1. Check the updates.
2. If there are any updates, record and submit a separate command buffer that transforms my textures from read-only optimal to transfer dst optimal.
3. If there are any updates, record transfer commands and issue transform back to read-only optimal in main command buffer.
4. Otherwise, just use textures as is without any transformations.

Is this a good approach? Are there any other ways to accomplish a reduction of such layout transforms?
I also consider just using `VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_GENERAL`.

Comment: Most optimal-to-optimal layout transitions are no-ops, so use a profiler to determine if you are actually optimizing something that needs optimizing before you waste time on this.

Comment: Try to avoid using `VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_GENERAL` for GPU-side operations. It's slower than optimal layouts (that's why optimal layouts exist).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just understood that I forgot that I can track the state of texture myself.

For example, in my question, there is 3 possible states and corresponding layouts of a texture:

1. It is just created: `VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_UNDEFINED`
2. It was used in graphics pipeline and didn't have any transfers into it recently: `VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_SHADER_READ_ONLY_OPTIMAL`
3. There was a transfer into it so it has layout `VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_DST_OPTIMAL`.

So we can store a state in a enum:

```c
enum TextureState{
   just_created,
   used_for_render,
   had_transfer,
}
```

And access it during recording our command buffers every frame (pseudocode):

```c
// Copying data to texture.
if (need_to_copy_to_texture) {
   if (tex_state == TextureState::had_transfer) {
      // Do nothing, we already in compatible layout
   }
   else if (tex_state == TextureState::just_created) {
      // Need VkImageMemoryBarrier here
      pipeline barrier VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_UNDEFINED =>
           VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_DST_OPTIMAL
   }
   else if (tex_state == TextureState::used_for_render) {
      // Need VkImageMemoryBarrier here
      pipeline barrier VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_SHADER_READ_ONLY_OPTIMAL =>
           VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_DST_OPTIMAL
   }
   record copy of data to texture;
   tex_state = TextureState::had_transfer;
}

// Now we want to render
if (tex_state == TextureState::used_for_render) {
  // Do nothing, we already in compatible layout for rendering
  // because there weren't any transfers after last rendering.
}
else if (tex_state == TextureState::just_created) {
  // This probably should not happen.
  assert(false);
}
else if (tex_state == TextureState::had_transfer) {
  // Need VkImageMemoryBarrier here
  pipeline barrier VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_DST_OPTIMAL =>
       VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_SHADER_READ_ONLY_OPTIMAL
}
tex_state = TextureState::used_for_render;

begin rendering;
bind pipeline with our texture;
bind descriptor set with out texture;
issue draw call;
end rendering;

submit command buffer to a queue;
```

This way we ensure that:

1. We always have correct layout of texture for every operation.
2. We do transfers between texture layouts only when it is required so no wasting GPU cycles doing unneeded job.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure it's an actual issue? drivers know that the next layout transfer after a dst_optimal is likely going to be a read_only. So it's very unlikely that those transitions will actually do anything.

If you do a full overwrite of the texture when there are changes then the workflow should be:

```
if(image_changed){
    pipeline barrier from VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_UNDEFINED to VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_DST_OPTIMAL 
    vkCmdCopyBufferToImage(cmd, staging_buffer, texture, VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_DST_OPTIMAL, 1, &region);
    //copy from staging buffer to texture
    pipeline barrier from VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_DST_OPTIMAL to VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_SHADER_READ_ONLY_OPTIMAL
}
```

`VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_UNDEFINED` as `src` lets the driver discard the old data entirely skipping one of the transitions.

This assumes that `image_changed` is a decent enough check.

Comment: No, texture provider updates chunks of the textures while keeping other parts usable. It is a good trick for completely changing textures though.